# Transit visa for 2 layovers one in Paris and then in Amsterdam

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, layovers, paris, amsterdam

I am planning to visit India from USA. I will be having 2 layovers 1st in Paris and then in Amsterdam. Do I need any kind of visa for this trip?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you flying through Paris on your way to India and Amsterdam on your way back to the US, or is there a flight between Paris and Amsterdam?

Comment: Yes, You got it right @phoog

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a Schengen visa, as the flight between Paris and Amsterdam will not be an international flight, but an intra-Schengen flight (not sure if that is the exact term).  You might look into changing your flights so that you only transit one EU airport enroute to the USA.